# How to acquire a table result set from "Table - valued function" when the result set has variable structures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, set-returning-functions, table-valued-parameters

I need to write a Table - valued function from which I can acquire a table result set with different structure each time.
another thing is that I need to declare variables inside my function .
I've search for more that 3 hours but I could not find anything regarding this issue.
Is there any way to do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please it is not clear what are you trying to achieve. Try to improve your question by adding some example.

Comment: Sounds like you want a stored procedure using dynamic SQL, not a table-valued function (functions can't use dynamic SQL, and inline TVFs - the only ones that benefit performance-wise from being functions - can't use local variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema (column names, data types, etc) returned by a TVF (or view) is determined when the object is created. It cannot be dynamic, varying at execution time.

Views and TVFs should be used logically much like a table, where the schema is a contract between the database and application. It will wreak havoc if columns come and go or change between executions.